# A better way to improve blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

There are two type of packages that a customer can choose from: Phone packages or Broadband & Phone Packages.

When user ready to place an order, it will show a summary view with package name information and the cost. Some Summary information does not need to show if they select Phone package or Broadband & Phone Package.

Is there a better way to improve the readability and maintainable? For example

**order-sidebar.blade.php**

Note: This is small example of block of code. In the real application it is quite large with a lot of `if` statement `broadbandphone` or `phone`

```
@if ($summary['service'] == "phone" ||  $summary['service'] == "broadbandphone")
    <div class="x5">

        <h4>Phone Line x <span class="summary-lines">{{$summary['lines']}}</span></h4>


        <ul class="clearfix">
            @if ($summary['service'] == "phone")
                <li>
                    <p class="x5-details">
                        @if ($summary['line_type'] == "newline")
                            New Line(s)
                        @endif

                        @if ($summary['line_type'] == "switch")
                            Switch line(s)
                        @endif
                    </p>
                </li>
            @endif

            @if ($summary['service'] == "phone" && $summary['lines'] > 1)
                <li>
                    <p class="x5-details">{{$summary['linesWithMulitpleNumbers']}}</p>
                </li>
            @endif

            <li>
                <p class="x5-details">{{$summary['package']->name}}</p>

                <p class="x5-price">£{{$summary['monthlyLinesCost']}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
@endif
```

Or should I do two separate files for summary view like `order-sidebar-phone.blade.php` and `order-sidebar-broadbandphone.blade.php`

So it would be something like this:

```
   @if ($summary['service'] == "phone")
        @include('sections.order-sidebar-phone')
   @end

   @if ($summary['service'] == "broadbandphone")
        @include('sections.order-sidebar-broadbandphone')
   @end
```

Comment: Is `$summary` an Eloquent model?

Comment: @lukasgeiter No. `$summary` has been declared in OrderController.php file via `generateSummary()` method. `generateSummary()` calculate the costs, total price, etc via sessions and database.

Comment: @lukasgeiter can you advice me what to improve on blade

Comment: Can you post the full code to a site like pastebin so I can see what's going on here?

Comment: Thanks, but I actually meant the full view code ;)

Comment: @lukasgeiter updated, scroll down to see view code https://gist.github.com/striketest/e0025a58c3977e7a9ac2 (I haven't finish view code yet but I will be adding a lot of `if ($summary['service'] == "phone")` and `if ($summary['service'] == "broadbandphone")`

Comment: I still don't see "a lot of if statement `broadbandphone` or `phone`". And by the way, this question might be better off on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh ok. How would you do differently?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69063/discussion-between-ill-be-back-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks okay to me. However here are some tips that might help reducing if's or making your code more readable.

#### Shorthand ternary if

Sometimes a [shorthand if](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) looks cleaner and more readable:

```
@if($summary['service'] == "phone")
    Foo
@else
    Bar
@endif
```

Can be written as:

```
{{ ($summary['service'] == "phone" ? "Foo" : "Bar") }}
```

It's especially useful for just little pieces of text that change depending on a condition.

#### Indentation

I shouldn't even need to say that. Indent your code right (not saying you didn't in your question...) And your if statements will be less confusing ;)

#### Partials

While it is an option to split it up completely like you suggested, this can cause a lot of duplicate code...

But you can also split your files so they are not as big and don't contain so many if statements (even if the total is still the same it's better structured and clearer)

For example instead of:

```
{{-- ... --}
</div> 
    
@if ($summary['newSetup'] == false)
    <div class="installation">
        <h4>Phone Line x <span class="summary-lines">{{$summary['lines']}}</span></h4>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li>
                <p class="installation-details">Installation</p>
                <p class="installation-price">£{{$summary['installationCharge']}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<div class="off-costs bg-gray">
     <div class="off-costs-header clearfix">
{{-- ... --}}
```

Put the `installation` part in it's own file and include it:

```
{{-- ... --}
</div> 
    
@if ($summary['newSetup'] == false)
    @include('installation')
@endif

<div class="off-costs bg-gray">
     <div class="off-costs-header clearfix">
{{-- ... --}}
```